# reference asp.net core web application from .net core console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET core 3.0 web application (to setup a SignalR server) i want to start from a .net core console application. However, whenever i set the output type of the ASP.NET application to 'Console application' and reference it from a simple test .net core application i get the following error upon building:

```
Error: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.
```

It also complains it cannot find the .dll file for the web application, but i guess that is because of the other build error.
Whenever i set the ASP.NET core 3.0 web application output type to 'Class library' however, everything builds just fine. Only when i try to start the web application from the console application it only partially starts. I can clearly see the SignalR service and endpoint are being added, but when i try to connect a client to the SignalR server this isnt possible. What am i missing? why cant i start the asp.net core web application from the .net core console application?

Good to note: when i start the web application from a main function within the web application itself (using the same code as i use in the console application) everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply just reference the project. It won't *do* anything, because it needs to actually be running. You need to publish and deploy the ASP.NET Core app, and then access it via HTTP from your console app.

Comment: I get that i need to initialize and call the 'start' function in the ASP.NET core application. The purpose of doing this from a separate project is that we have a main application that starts multiple modules/plugins/whatever you want to call them. The ASP.NET core application is just one of those modules.
I currently have the reference working. The main problem was a blocking call in the deploy function that made the ASP.net core application not finalize the deployment somehow. For some reason this problem doesnt occur when i start the application as standalone though.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not start the web app from a console app. You should deploy it with options from [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

For testing purpose, you could follow steps below:

1. Reference Asp.net Core web app from .net core console app
2. Add code below to `Program.cs` in Console App

   ```
   CoreAPI.Program.Main(args);

   namespace ConsoleApp1
   {
   class Program
   {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
                Console.WriteLine("Start .net core");
                CoreAPI.Program.Main(args);           
           }
   }    
   }
   ```